# AppIntent error when running in app killed state without openAppWhenRun

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts, appintents

On iOS, when trying to run an AppIntent that's added to the Shortcuts app and my app is in a killed state, I get the following error: `Error Domain=LNActionForAutoShortcutPhraseFetchError Code=1 "Couldn't find AppshortcutsProvider." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't find AppShortcutsProvider`. It *seems* from the error that the AppShortcutsProvider cannot be found, however when I run the shortcut when the app is not in a killed state, it runs perfectly fine.

Relevant code below:

```
struct ExampleIntent: AppIntent, WidgetConfigurationIntent {
        
    static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Title"
    static let description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("Description")
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        // Performing relevant logic
        return .result(
            dialog: IntentDialog(stringLiteral: "Result message")
        )
    }
}
```

AppShortcutsProvider (in the main app, not in an extension):

```
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct ExampleShortcutsProvider: AppShortcutsProvider {
        
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: ExampleIntent(),
            phrases: ["Perform the example intent"],
            shortTitle: "Example Shortcut",
            systemImageName: "info.circle.fill"
        )
    }
}
```

If I add `static let openAppWhenRun: Bool = true` to the ExampleIntent, it runs perfectly fine, also when the app is in a killed state. I could not find any documentation on this - does anyone know why this is the behavior?